# Android – How to interrupt/cancel long calculation/AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to calculate a BigDecimal pow (and roots), but for very large numbers this operation takes 10 or more seconds. Therefore I created the following AsyncTask:

```
class CalculateTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //...
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        tvStatus.setText("Started calculation...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {         
        val2 = val1.pow(largeValue); //Long operation    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //...
    }
}
```

And then I call this AsyncTask from an Activity:

```
CalculateTask calculateTask;
void calculate() {    
    calculateTask = new CalculateTask();
    calculateTask.execute(largeValue);
}
```

But sometimes it is required to interrupt the calculation from the Activity. Could you please advice, how to interrupt the AsyncTask?

I sow some examples on StackOverflow related to isCancelled(), but I don't know how to apply it here.

Answer (score 1):

If the long operation really is just one call, you can't apply the standard solution of checking `isCancelled()` in a loop.

The simple solution would be to just let it run, but make sure the `AsyncTask` isn't holding onto any hard references to the context.  Or just don't worry about leaking a context for a few seconds, and make sure the activity is still running before trying to touch its UI.

The complicated solution would be to implement your own replacement for `BigDecimal#pow(...)` that checks `isCancelled()` in its innermost loop.

Answer (score 0):

From SDK documentation:

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). 
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled()  to
>   return true.

If so then add to `doInBackground()` method condition that checks for `isCancelled()` method.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
   while (!isCancelled())
   {
      // do some stuff
      val2 = val1.pow(largeValue); //Long operation
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** This code works only if you have multiple power calculations in that loop and then you cancel your task between them.

Comment: That won't work if the long operation is just one call to an external method.  `BigDecimal#pow(...)` won't stop just because the calling `AsyncTask` is cancelled.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Yup, you're right. That won't stop this power calculation. Maybe this must be done by usual threads then?

Comment: You would do that by starting a `Thread` and calling `interrupt()` on it if you want to cancel it.  But `BigDecimal#pow(...)` is not guaranteed to check if the calling thread `isInterrupted()`.  The implementation I looked at does not.  So you're back to either letting it run or reimplementing `pow(...)` to check the interruption status.